# Check user auth on every Activity

Tags: android, performance, api

Is it appropriate to check user auth to server api in every activity (i assume using base activity on resume)? It is to prevent user login on multiple device with same account. Or is there better approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several approach to handle this.

1. **Push notification** - When same user login in another device then you need to send push notification to first login device. When first login device get notification then you can put your logic there.
2. **Put Logout status on every api** - You need to check logout status code in every api response. When you get logout status code then you can put your logic there.

**Note:** For second approach you need to make one generic api calling class. So, You don't need to put this status code in every api calling code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming that every successful sign-in then the server gives you back a unique auth-token which should invalidate any previously assigned token.

My approach is usually just to allow the user to continue using the app with whatever cached data that's already there until I hit a scenario that needs to do an API call.  And if I get an error code like HTTP 401 or 403 because the auth token was invalidated then should send me back to the sign-in screen.

Doing an explicit API call in onResume() seems wasteful and is basically client-side polling I would only do this if it was a very strict requirement to keep the auth information fresh because the information on screen is sensitive.